# Javascript: How to convert a list of objects with many key-value pairs into one big nested object?

Tags: javascript

for example, from this:

```
const items = [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "orgId": 2,
            "mod": "toyota",
            "part": "wheel",
            "price": 333
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "orgId": 2,
            "mod": "toyota",
            "part": "shell",
            "price": 350
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "orgId": 2,
            "mod": "honda",
            "part": "wheel",
            "price": 222
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "orgId": 2,
            "mod": "honda",
            "part": "shell",
            "price": 250
        }
    ]
```

and convert to:

```
items = {
    "toyota": {"wheel": 333, "shell": 350 }, 
    "honda": {"wheel": 222, "shell": 250 }
}
```

What is the most elegant way?

I was trying to use `.map()` but I'm not sure how to complete the nested struture.

---

Follow up:

Using this method:

```
      const structure = {};
      prices.forEach((e) => {
       structure[e.mod] ??= {};
       structure[e.mod][e.part] = e.price;
      });
```

or:

```
      result = items.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.mod] ??= {};
        r[o.mod][o.part] = o.price;
        return r;
      },{});
```

I got the following error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (56:31)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       const structure = {};
|       prices.forEach(e => {
>         structure[e.mod] ??= {};
|         structure[e.mod][e.part] = e.price;
|       });
```

I have done quite a lot searching but cannot find how to solve it.

Any advices?

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). What have you tried with `.map`? This sounds more like a job for `reduce` (or a `forEach` which adds onto an object).

Comment: What should happen in case of duplicate records ?

Comment: @MaxZoom Override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the code below:

```
const transformedItems = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.mod] = { ...acc[item.mod], [item.part]: item.price }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(transformedItems)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!  Could you please take a look at the follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850278/typescript-type-null-cannot-be-used-as-an-index-type-in-array-reduce-accumu?  If this is running in Typescript, it shows an error.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array#reduce` to group based on `mod`.

```js
const items = [ { "id": 3, "orgId": 2, "mod": "toyota", "part": "wheel", "price": 333 }, { "id": 4, "orgId": 2, "mod": "toyota", "part": "shell", "price": 350 }, { "id": 9, "orgId": 2, "mod": "honda", "part": "wheel", "price": 222 }, { "id": 10, "orgId": 2, "mod": "honda", "part": "shell", "price": 250 } ],
      result = items.reduce((r, o) => {
        r[o.mod] ??= {};
        r[o.mod][o.part] = o.price;
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got a `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (56:31)` error using ` r[o.mod] ??= {};`  ( see the updated post). Could you please comment?

Comment: Try this `r[o.mod] ||= {};` instead of `r[o.mod] ??= {};`

Answer (score 0):

I think the most confortable structure will be this

```
items = {
    "toyota": {"wheel": 333, "shell": 350 }, 
    "honda": {"wheel": 222, "shell": 250 }
}
```

because you make sure to get unique elements

```js
const items = [{
  "id": 3,
  "orgId": 2,
  "mod": "toyota",
  "part": "wheel",
  "price": 333
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "orgId": 2,
  "mod": "toyota",
  "part": "shell",
  "price": 350
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "orgId": 2,
  "mod": "honda",
  "part": "wheel",
  "price": 222
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "orgId": 2,
  "mod": "honda",
  "part": "shell",
  "price": 250
}];

const structure = {};
items.forEach((e) => {
 structure[e.mod] ??= {};
 structure[e.mod][e.part] = e.price;
});

console.log(structure)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got a `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (56:31)` error using `structure[e.mod] ??= {};`  ( see the updated post). Could you please comment?

Answer (score 0):

You could also iterate through items and populate the `result` object as below:

```js
const items = [ { "id": 3, "orgId": 2, "mod": "toyota", "part": "wheel", "price": 333 }, { "id": 4, "orgId": 2, "mod": "toyota", "part": "shell", "price": 350 }, { "id": 9, "orgId": 2, "mod": "honda", "part": "wheel", "price": 222 }, { "id": 10, "orgId": 2, "mod": "honda", "part": "shell", "price": 250 } ];

const result = {};
items.forEach((e) => {
  result[e.mod] = {...result[e.mod], [e.part]: e.price};
});

console.log(result);
```